# Sphinx - search more than doc. IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm searching with PHP Sphinx in my products database:

```
SELECT name, price FROM products
```

I'm searching only by name.
I'm using pagination because I don't need all record at once ( ->SetLimits()  ) so Sphinx return me e.g. only 10 ids.

But web user can filter searched items by price filter, so I need to know max and min price (from all records not just from records on one page) to show user price filter range.

Is it possible get from Sphinx MAX(price) and MIN(price) values from all searched decuments?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping/Clustering allows this
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#clustering

You run your normal text query, as we as another query to get the data you need.

If worried about performance, use multi-queries
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#multi-queries